# printing out an object in javascript into html dom

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to print out an object into an HTML DOM in various different ways, so I can understand how it works better.

But the result looks like that:

> Store and retrieve data from local storage. John undefinedJohn 31 New York

As you can see, it returns "undefinedJohn", and I have no clue why. Can someone explain to me? Suggestions for other ways to display objects, arrays and JSON in HTML would also be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Store and retrieve data from local storage.</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myObj, myJSON, text, obj, temp;

var idx = 0;

// Storing data:
myObj = { name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York" };
myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
localStorage.setItem("testJSON", myJSON);

// Retrieving data:
text = localStorage.getItem("testJSON");
obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += Object.values(obj)+`<br>`;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(obj)+`<br><br>`;
console.log(obj);
for (idx in obj) {
    console.log(obj[idx]);
    console.log(idx);
    temp += obj[idx] + " " + "<br>";
};

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += temp;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems to work fine, codepen: https://codepen.io/kethan1/pen/zYZvyVX

Comment: @KetZoomer
thanks for your replay!
yes, it works - but it returns  undefinedJohn instead of just John when i print it out:

Comment: you never define an initial value for `temp` but then use addition assignment on it so it adds the first string you provide to its initial value which is `undefined`. just assign it an initial value to avoid it. `var myObj, myJSON, text, obj, temp = '';`

Comment: Also you should read up on `for ... in` to avoid unexpected output, [for...in#iterating_over_own_properties_only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#iterating_over_own_properties_only)

Comment: @pilchard
oh i see, i'll do it from now on when declaring vars.
and i'll read more about `for...in`

thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you declared **temp** variable but didn't initialized it, hence it is taking undefined as a value, simply follow below working code, **temp =''**:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2>Store and retrieve data from local storage.</h2>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var myObj, myJSON, text, obj, temp ='';

var idx = 0;

// Storing data:
myObj = { name: "John", age: 31, city: "New York" };
myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
localStorage.setItem("testJSON", myJSON);

// Retrieving data:
text = localStorage.getItem("testJSON");
obj = JSON.parse(text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += Object.values(obj)+`<br>`;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(obj)+`<br><br>`;
console.log(obj);
for (idx in obj) {
    console.log(obj[idx]);
    console.log(idx);
    temp += obj[idx] + " " + "<br>";
};

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += temp;
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

It says `undefinedJohn` because you did not declare the variable `temp`. So, the default value is `undefined`. When you add a different string on to `undefined`, like `'John'`, it will become `'undefinedJohn'`.

Comment: temp variable is already created, just dedn't declared